# purpose of setURLStreamHandlerFactory in URL Class

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

Can anyone explain to me the purpose and working of `setURLStreamHandlerFactory` in the `URL` class?

I have a simple code snippet to connect to my HDFS using `URL` class in Java, which I have gone through in hadoop definitive guide.

This is the code I've written:

```
public class HadoopFileSystemConnect {

    static {
        URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("hdfs://localhost:9000/employee_data.txt");
        InputStream in = url.openStream();
        IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out,4096,false);
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me the purpose and working of the statement in the static block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java has a default class (sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler) used for handling streams when you call URL.openStream().  The method in the static block replaces the default java handler with Hadoop one, that's all.